# Error : Cannot read property push of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, constructor, static

I'm trying to import a static array that will be used in two different classes, but when I try to push the arguments through the array parameter it gives me an error.

**First Class:**

```
const ChargingStation = require('./chargingStation')           
class Scooter {
  constructor(scooterID, color, speed, battery)
  {
    if (!scooterID) {
      throw new Error("Please insert Scooter ID")
    }

    this.scooterID = scooterID
    this.color = color
    this.speed = speed
    this.battery = battery
    ChargingStation.allScooter.push(scooterID) // <--- This is the line that throws the error
  } 
  module.exports = Scooter
```

**Second Class:**

```
class ChargingStation {
  static allScooter = []
    constructor() {}
    module.exports = ChargingStation
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that each class is above/below each other, rather than next to each other.

Comment: Now I've seen everything, paginated code ...

Comment: first console  this `ChargingStation.allScooter` and check the value inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of chargingStation in root folder to ChargingStation, restarted my IDE and it started working.